# What can (and what can't) throw an exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception

Is there complete list (maybe recursively defined) of "code statements" that can lead to exception in c++? Something like this:

1) `throw` statement (naturally)

2) calls to `new`

3) calls to any functions from standard library that are documented to be able to throw.

4) calls to any user-defined functions (including constructors) that contain operations from 1-3.

5) Something else? Allocating local objects on stack, operations on built-in types, dereferencing pointers, type casts - are they able to throw?

6) Everything else is exception-free.

By exception-free I don't mean operations that are always successful. Dereferencing a pointer surely isn't. But still it does not make sense to wrap it in `try-catch` block, think about exception-safety of function dereferencing a pointer, etc. So the code that either successful or leads to undefined behaviour can be considered as exception-free.

**Upd.** Despite my last paragraph I still got a comment that undefined behaviour also can throw, so let me explain what I mean. Consider following code:

```
void bar();
Class C{
...
public:
  foo() {
    something_that_breaks_class_invariants;
    bar();
    something_that_restores_class_invariants;
  }
}
```

If I correctly understand what exception safety is about, then **if `bar()` can throw exception, this code is bad.** I should change the order of statements, or I should wrap `bar()` in `try-catch` block, restore class invariants and propagate exception further.

But if bar() either successfully returns or leads to undefined behaviour (because, I don't know, something else is broken), then `foo()` is ok. `foo()` can't do anything and shouldn't care about possible undefined behaviour of `bar()`. In this sense `bar()` is exception-free, can be marked `noexcept`, etc.

So my question is: what kinds of statements can be in `bar()` to consider it exception-free is this sense?

Comment: Start with assuming everything can throw.  Then if you need to prove it does not.  This smells of an XY problem.

Comment: Any undefined behavior could result in an exception being thrown...

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to wrap `std::vector::at` in a try-catch either.

Comment: **Richard Critten** , how can I prove that something doesn't throw without such a list? What if `int x=5; return x;` can throw?

Comment: @RichardCritten functions marked `noexcept` don't throw (they abort the program instead)

Comment: @Caleth: well, those functions are exceptions (pun intended) to the rule

Comment: This may help you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec

Comment: @Caleth By having undefined behavior even those function can throw...

Comment: @skyking the behaviour is defined. std::terminate is called if a thrown exception reaches the outermost block of a `noexept(true)` function

Comment: @Caleth Unless there is a undefined behaviour somewhere. Then the standard does not impose any restrictions on behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the list of things that can throw in C++ can be exhaustively defined.

- `throw` expression
- `new` can throw `bad_alloc`
- `dynamic_cast` can throw `bad_cast`
- `typeid` can throw `bad_typeid`
- any call to a function that is not `noexcept` or `throw()`

The last point also applies to all the implicit function calls of C++: default/copy/move constructors, overloaded operators, destructors (note that those default to `noexcept`) and conversion operators.

If you are ever in doubt about a particular expression, you can use the `noexcept` operator to have the compiler tell you whether it's theoretically possible for the expression to throw.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is almost complete. There's indeed one cast that can throw: `dynamic_cast<Derived&>`. That's because there are no null references. `dynamic_cast<Derived*>` returns a null pointer instead of throwing.

In **all** cases, exceptions are thrown when evaluating *expressions*. Variable definitions may only throw when they contain an expression, e.g. in an initializer or inside a constructor.

The "Undefined Behavior" bit is a red herring. You simply can't reason about a C++ program that has Undefined Behavior, not even about what might have happened prior to that UB. That means we're assuming no UB whenever we are reasoning about defined C++ behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: Any statement that uses an overloadable operator or function that cannot be proven not to throw, can throw. Here are some examples:

```
template <class T> T foo(const T& arg) { return arg; }    //can throw (copy constructor!)
template <class T> void foo(T a, T b) { a+b; }    //can throw (+ is overloadable)

template <class T>
void foo(T iter, T end) {
    for(; iter < end; iter++) {    //both the < and the ++ operator can throw
        iter->bar();    //even the -> operator is overloadable and can throw
    }
}
```

In short, whenever you do not have knowledge of the involved types, as is generally the case with templates, you pretty much have to call any statement a throwing statement.

Afaik, the only valid defense against this not to allow exceptions in the first place.